# How to make Reflection for getting the field value by its string name and its original type

Tags: scala, reflection

When trying to get object field by its string name, the value returned, not by correct scala type. As:

```
import scala.language.reflectiveCalls
import scala.language.implicitConversions

case class Intity(flag: Boolean, id: Int, name: String)
val inty =  Intity(false, 123, "blue")

implicit def reflect(r: AnyRef) = new {
  def get(n:String) = {
    val c = r.getClass.getDeclaredField(n)
    c.setAccessible(true); c}
  def getVal(n: String) = get(n).get(r)
  def getType (n:String) = get(n).getType
 }
```

then when using this

```
inty.getType("flag")     // res0: Class[_] = boolean  --not Boolean
inty.getVal("id")        // res1: Object = 123    --Object not Int
```

Any efficient way of doing the above implementation?

Comment: Instead of reflection, would [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) be able to solve your problem?

Comment: @Reactormonk but how, i don't know much about hapless so far. would it support an access to class attributes by its string name and return the value by original type, ?

Comment: You're never going to get the precise type at compile time by using runtime reflection. Think about it.

Comment: @Jasper-M, should be a way to that. i tried shapeless, not giving exactly what i want :(.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure, how one can return different types from a single function.
But you can infer the correct type of any Class attribute using scala reflect api(s).

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe => ru}
implicit class ForAnyInstance[T: ru.TypeTag](i: T)(implicit c: scala.reflect.ClassTag[T]) {

    /* a mirror sets a scope of the entities on which we have reflective access */
    val mirror = ru.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)

    /* here we get an instance mirror to reflect on an instance */
    val im = ru.runtimeMirror(i.getClass.getClassLoader)

    def fieldInfo(name: String) = {
      ru.typeOf[T].members.filter(!_.isMethod).filter(_.name.decoded.trim.equals(name)).foreach(s => {
        val fieldValue = im.reflect(i).reflectField(s.asTerm).get

        /* typeSignature contains runtime type information about a Symbol */
        s.typeSignature match {
          case x if x =:= ru.typeOf[String] => /* do something */
          case x if x =:= ru.typeOf[Int] => /* do something */
          case x if x =:= ru.typeOf[Boolean] => /* do something */
        }
      })
    }
}
```

And then invoke it as:

```
case class Entity(flag: Boolean, id: Int, name: String)
val e = Entity(false, 123, "blue")
e.fieldInfo("flag")
e.fieldInfo("id")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something similar at compile time with shapeless.

```
scala> import shapeless._
import shapeless._

scala> val inty = Intity(false, 123, "blue")
inty: Intity = Intity(false,123,blue)        

scala> val intyGen = LabelledGeneric[Intity].to(inty)
intyGen: shapeless.::[Boolean with shapeless.labelled.KeyTag[Symbol with shapeless.tag.Tagged[String("flag")],Boolean],shapeless.::[Int with shapeless.labelled.KeyTag[Symbol with shapeless.tag.Tagged[String("id")],Int],shapeless.::[String with shapeless.labelled.KeyTag[Symbol with shapeless.tag.Tagged[String("name")],String],shapeless.HNil]]] = false :: 123 :: blue :: HNil

scala> import shapeless.record._
import shapeless.record._

scala> intyGen.get('flag)
res10: Boolean = false

scala> intyGen.get(Symbol("id"))
res11: Int = 123
```